# different charset for multiple params with dllimport

Tags: c#, c++, interop

Is it possible to declare different charset options for seperate params?

heres what i mean:

```
[dllimport("my.dll", charset = charset.Ansi)]
void myfunc(string CharPtrInCPP, StringBuilder WCharPtrInCPP);
```

the problem is the c++ function takes a char* for the filename and a wchar* for the data recieved back...

in c++:

```
void myfuncImpl(char *filename, WCHAR *buffer, int len); 
//another method, myfunc, wraps this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already pointed out, you should be able to specify MarshalAs for each parameter.  Another way would be to specify a default character set type and then specify the marshalling for the odd one out.  For example,

```
  [DllImport("my.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
  void myfunc( [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.LPStr )] String filename, 
               StringBuilder buffer, int len );
```

Comment: Eek, not string for the write back buffer.  StringBuilder.

Comment: @Hans, Ah yes.  I should actually read the question.  Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify [`[MarshalAs]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) for each parameter.

Try the following:

```
[DllImport("my.dll")]
void myfunc(
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string CharPtrInCPP, 
     [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] StringBuilder WCharPtrInCPP,
     int len
   );
```